# How do I align to vertically center my jumbotron and navbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I like to ask how can I vertically align my jumbotron and navbar to the center? I've been working on this for a whole day and still can't figure it out. 
Really appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project_T.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="d_flex vh-100">
        <div class=".container-fluid m-auto">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
                <h1> Welcome to <div style="font-family:'Nunito',sans-serif">Project_T </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Buy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://imgur.com/gallery/AkqBoqr

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `m-auto` which sets `margin-left` and `margin-right` so as to make content at the centre in the navbar.

This is it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project_T.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="d_flex vh-100">
            <div class=".container-fluid m-auto">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
                    <h1> Welcome to <div style="font-family:'Nunito',sans-serif">Project_T </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark ">
                <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Buy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active m-auto">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/2ow7xa3f/

Answer (score -1):

```
Replace your code with this. 
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project_T.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center vh-100">
            <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
                    <h1> Welcome to <span style="font-family:Nunito,sans-serif">Project_T</span></h1>    
            </div>
            <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Buy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Help the user try to address the issue that he is facing. Explain what mistake the user has done. and what you are proposing to resolve the issue. Be clear and constructive when giving feedback. [Code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)